How to show these functions with Laguerre polynomials are the same
In the context of quantum mechanics, the overlap $|<m|D(\alpha)|n>|^2$ between a Fock state $|m>$ and a displaced Fock state $D(\alpha)|n>$ can be written as
$$
f = \dfrac{m!}{n!}e^{-|\alpha|^2}(|\alpha|^2)^{(n-m)}L_m^{n-m}[|\alpha|^2]^2 \qquad\text{for $m<n$}
$$
$$
g = \dfrac{n!}{m!}e^{-|\alpha|^2}(|\alpha|^2)^{(m-n)}L_n^{m-n}[|\alpha|^2]^2 \qquad\text{for $n\leq m$}
$$
here, $\alpha$ is a complex number (only $|\alpha|^2$ matters though), and $L_n^{k}[x]$ are the generalized Laguerre polynomials. The indexes $m,n$ are non-negative integers.
Now, I know that by definition $f=g$, which I checked to be true also numerically with Mathematica. However, is there a way, for example using properties of the Laguerre polynomials, to show that the two expressions above coincide?
